# Running scrapy without creating scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a scrapy project in python. So I created two scripts:

`dmoz_spider.py` and `items.py`:

```
$ cat dmoz_spider.py
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

$ cat items.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


##class TutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
 ##   pass

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

What I really want to know is, how can I change my code in order to be able to run it with the following code:

```
$ python dmoz_spider.py
```

And get my results...

How should I change my code?

Comment: use the spider's `name` not its filename

Comment: Tahnk you, How can I change the code?

Comment: `scrapy crawl dmoz`, I suggest to read the tutorial completely.

Comment: No I want not to run script using scrapy command. I want to write a seperate program and run my code with python <>.py command!

Comment: [Run scrapy from a script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at running Scrapy spider from a script. You can find the guideline for this here:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html